# MKMapview as an overlay

Tags: ios, objective-c, mapkit

Is it possible to have an `MKMapView` lined up on top of another `MKMapView` with the top having a level of transparency so you can see the bottom. Further when the user swipes, I would like BOTH the top and bottom map to scroll, or zoom in unison.

I am finding the standard map too plain and the satellite map too intense and was hoping to combine them for effect.

Any thoughts?

Comment: You may have occasionally performance issues in current phones. If that happens once, your user will feel frustrated. So let's try a more reliable way.

Comment: Are you looking for hybrid mode?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this, no problem at all. As you already described, just put a MKMapView in your window and a second one on top. Let's assume we call them _map1 and _map2,  the latter being on top of _map1. The MKMapViewDelegate protocol will let you know when a user scrolls/moves/zooms _map2, so you can tell _map1 to display the same visible region of _map2.

In my example I use a slider to set the level of transparency of _map2.

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@import MapKit;

@interface ViewController () <MKMapViewDelegate>
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet MKMapView *map1;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet MKMapView *map2;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISlider *alphaSlider;


@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    [_map1 setMapType:MKMapTypeSatellite];
    [_map2 setMapType:MKMapTypeStandard];
    [_map2 setAlpha:0.5];
    [_map2 setDelegate:self];
    [_alphaSlider addTarget:self action:@selector(sliderChanged) forControlEvents:UIControlEventAllEvents] ;
    _alphaSlider.value = _map2.alpha;
}

- (void)mapViewDidChangeVisibleRegion:(MKMapView *)mapView
{
    // _map2 is on top and will receive visible region updates, i.e. the user scrolled/moved/zoomed the map 
    // just pass the new region to _map1 so it will be similar to that one of _map2 
    [_map1 setRegion:_map2.region];
}

- (void)sliderChanged
{
    [_map2 setAlpha:_alphaSlider.value];
}
```

Comment: Awesome!! Thank you. it seems easy now that you look at it, but I could not find the IBActions or delegate commands.